# State-of-art of telecommunications?

Tags: digital-communications

There seems to be a number of different ways for telecommunication. What is the most recent (and maybe standard) technique used today? It seems the simple AM/FM modulations are definitely somewhere in the past, then there are these spread spectrum systems... All hints welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You should realize that when you say "telecommunications" you are talking about a huge field involving lots of different technologies.  Based on the mention of AM/FM modulations I infer that you are referring to digital (though AM/FM are actually analog) wireless transmission techniques (though I may have inferred incorrectly since wired modems can use some pretty sophisticated modulations).  Even restricting ourselves to wireless telecommunications, there are lots of different technologies that we could talk about- modulation types are just one.

Anyway, back to what I think you were asking.

The progression of modulation types went something like the following:

- AM (very simple analog)
- FM (more sophisticated analog- but uses more bandwidth than AM)
- OOK (very simple digital)
- FSK (digital version of FM)
- PSK
- QAM
- TCM
- DSSS
- OFDM

If you google any of the above terms and add "modulation", you should get some useful references.

OFDM is, as far as I am aware, the latest-and-greatest modulation type.  It has the useful feature of being extremely efficient at packing data into a given amount of bandwidth.  Since bandwidth is at a premium for the telecoms, that is very important.  Many of the other modulation types are still used though, and will continue to be used because they have other useful features.